# How to parse a string received from a socket?

Tags: c, sockets, c-strings

I'm new to C, and attempting to parse a string sent from a client. I've originally sent data in the following format "command value", and I want to store the command in a variable, and value in another variable.

I'm trying to use `strtok()`, but every time I attempt to parse the received string, I get a segfault.

What's wrong with my code, and how do I fix it?

```
   char buff[MAX]; 
   char command[32], value[32];
   int n; 

   // Loop to continually read

   for (;;) { 
     bzero(buff, MAX); 

     // read the message from client sent in format "command value"
     read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff)); 

     // Attempt to store string as variables separated by a space
     strcpy(command, strtok(buff , " "));
     strcpy(value, strtok(NULL, " "));

     printf("%s %s", command, value);
   }
```

Comment: `buff` is not certainly a _string_.  Re-code and use the return value of `read()`. Be mindful of the need for the _null character_.

Comment: Use `memset` instead of `bzero`. It's more portable and not deprecated. After changing that, using `sizeof(buff)-1` should fix your issue.

Comment: @JL2210 How would I replace Bzero with memset? Sorry If this is a stupid question..

Comment: `memset(buff, 0, MAX);`

Comment: @SrikanthSrinivas `memset(buff, 0, MAX);`

Comment: @JL2210 Still doesn't work. Changed ```sizeof(buff) - 1``` as well, same issue

Comment: @SrikanthSrinivas Can you compile with debug info `gcc -gdwarf-4 -g3` and run  the program under `gdb --args`?

Comment: You don't need either `bzero()` or `memset()`. You just need not to totally ignore the value returned by `read()`, which can indicate an error, end of stream, or the actual number of bytes received. All this is logically prior to any parsing difficulties you may have, which aren't evident in your question.

Comment: When asking for problems with code, first extract a [mcve], just to make sure you understand what the problem really is.

Comment: Assuming TCP, your design is borked anyway, as you are reading a byte stream.  The touchstone is to consider the case where read() returns having loaded only one byte into the buffer each time it is called.  Will your design handle that, (no:)?

Answer (score 3):

Code needs to ascertain how much data was read.  Use return value from `read()`,

Insure input is *null character* terminated if `buff` is to be used as a string.

```
for (;;) { 

  // If buff is handled as a string, read one less to insure room for a later \0
  ssize_t count = read(sockfd, buff, sizeof buff - 1); 

  if (count < 0) {
    // read error
    printf("Read error\n");
    break;
  }
  if (count == 0) {
    // All done
    break;
  }

  buff[count] = '\0';
  printf("<%.*s>\n", count, buff);
}
```

Comment: You also need to test for zero, and react correctly by closing the socket and exiting the loop.